# How to convert an enum to another type of enum nicely?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an enum of for example 'Status' (Failed , Successful) and I have another enum from a service which has its own Status enum (Failed, Successful, Unknown)

My question is how can I write something quick and nice to convert from their enum to mine?

Comment: You cannot. They have three states, you have two. What do you expect to magically happen to the third state?

Comment: @nvoigt What if I match the same enums, so they're the same then, how would you deal with that?

Comment: Personally, I would probably just delete one of them, why have two identical enums.

Comment: @nvoigt. Thanks for the tip. Might not have been right for OP, but it was for me. I'd second deleting a duplicate ENUM where it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You always can just use a `Map` or a `switch` statement:

```dart
import 'some_other_service.dart' as theirs;

Status statusFromTheirStatus(theirs.Status status) {
  switch (status) {
    case theirs.Status.Unknown:
    case theirs.Status.Failed:
      return Failed;
    case theirs.Status.Successful:
      return Successful;
  }
}
```

which gives you some flexibility for how to handle `Unknown`.  The above example assumes it's a failure (since typically typically are many ways to fail but only one way to succeed), but you alternatively could, say, throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum StatusA {failed , successful}
enum StatusB {failed , successful, unknown}

void myServiceB(StatusB state) => print(state);

StatusB convertEnum(StatusA state) {
  var _state = state.toString().split('.')[1];
  return StatusB.values.firstWhere((e) => e.toString().contains(_state));
}


void main(List<String> args) {
  var localState = StatusA.failed;
  myServiceB(convertEnum(localState));
}
```

Output:

```
StatusB.failed
```

Flutter has this function [describeEnum](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/describeEnum.html), it can be useful too.